# Locals in Javascript/JQuery like Locals in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a Js Application and want to have English and German locals, which i can switch via button.
Is there a way to insert locals from a extra file in a .js file, like the function `t'...'` in Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to do it directly and the reason is fairly simple too, erb is executed at the server side and javascript is a client side language which means its executed in your local browser, thats why if you even try to pass a variable between the two you'll have to make a request to the server, However this problem is tackled by calling an AJAX request, this AJAX request does the same thing as sending a new request to the server however it does that without refreshing or reloading the page to it gives the users the illusion that no request was made.

a guy asks a similar question here:

http://www.quora.com/Ruby-on-Rails/Can-I-pass-a-JavaScript-variable-to-a-Rails-method

and you can learn more about AJAX here:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp